# Two-dimensional dict assignment not meeting expectations

Tags: python, dictionary

The function's return not meeting expectations.

My env py2.7.11 centos6.5.

I hope the function return the return like this

```
{'www.baidu.com': {'3xx': 0, 'response_time': 0.126, '5xx': 0, '4xx': 1}, 
'www.google.com': {'3xx': 0, 'response_time': 0, '5xx': 0, '4xx': 0}}
```

But in fact it is return like that. The `send_dict['www.google.com']['response_time']` and `send_dict['www.google.com']['response_code']` shouldn't be assigned. But why?

```
{'www.baidu.com': {'3xx': 0, 'response_time': 0.126, '5xx': 0, '4xx': 1}, 
'www.google.com': {'3xx': 0, 'response_time': 0.126, '5xx': 0, '4xx': 1}}
```

The Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

sink_dict = {'sink_zabbix_monitor_keys': '3xx,4xx,5xx,response_time',
             'sink_zabbix_domain_keys': 'www.baidu.com,www.google.com'}
sub_send_dict = dict.fromkeys(sink_dict['sink_zabbix_monitor_keys'].split(','), 0)
send_dict = dict.fromkeys(sink_dict['sink_zabbix_domain_keys'].split(','), sub_send_dict)


def calculate_item(item):

    response_code_dict = dict.fromkeys(sink_dict['sink_zabbix_domain_keys'].split(','), 0)
    response_time_dict = dict.fromkeys(sink_dict['sink_zabbix_domain_keys'].split(','), 0)
    domain = item['domain']
    response_code_dict[domain] = int(item['response_code'])
    response_time_dict[domain] = float(item['response_time'])
    if domain in send_dict:
        print domain
        if response_time_dict[domain] > float(send_dict[domain]['response_time']):
            send_dict[domain]['response_time'] = response_time_dict[domain]
        send_dict[domain][str(response_code_dict[domain])[0] + "xx"] += 1
    return send_dict

tmp_item = {'domain': 'www.baidu.com', 'response_time': '0.126', 'response_code': '401'}
tmp_item1 = {'domain': 'www.google.com', 'response_time': '0.126', 'response_code': '401'}
tmp_item2 = {'domain': 'www.baidu.com', 'response_time': '0.166', 'response_code': '401'}

print calculate_item(tmp_item)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and describe what your code is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
send_dict = {k: sub_send_dict.copy() for k in sink_dict['sink_zabbix_domain_keys'].split(',')}
```

This is called dict comprehension. This works because I'm assigning a [shallow copy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) of the dictionary to the key. `dict.fromkeys()` will assign the value to every key, all keys will share the same `sub_send_dict` reference.

From the (linked) python docs:

> Assignment statements in Python do not copy objects, they create bindings between a target and an object. For collections that are mutable or contain mutable items, a copy is sometimes needed so one can change one copy without changing the other.